# Enumerating slides in beamer without losing the footline

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm facing what it looks like a relatively simple problem but yet hard for me to solve.

In beamer I have this footline in every slide as shown in this picture:

[image: 1]

The missing thing is obviously the slides enumeration.

When I tried `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]`, my footline was suddenly gone and replaced with page numbers as shown here:

[image: 2]

So my point is, what do I need to do to include page enumeration inside the footline like this?

[image: 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beamer has a special template to adjust the numbering:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{text}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\begin{document}
    
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]